# IMAP what type of header encoding is this?

Tags: php, email, encoding, imap

Why does my subject look like this?

```
From: "Website Magazine"
 <news@websitemagazine.com>
To: xxxxxxxxx@aol.com
Date: 20 Sep 2012 15:36:20 -0400
Subject: =?utf-8?B?MTQgTmV3LWlzaCBBUEnigJlzIGZvciBEZXZlbG9wZXIgSW5z?=
 =?utf-8?B?cGlyYXRpb24=?=
```

In gmail it reads as `14 New-ish API’s for Developer Inspiration`

I'm using PHP, but just telling me **what type of encoding that is** should be enough for me to parse it.

Comment: Also note that this is an "encoding" not an "encryption".

Comment: @Xeoncross I can't believe noone else commented on that.

Comment: That's header encoding, you can decode it using [`imap_mime_header_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is [base64 encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

```
 print base64_decode('MTQgTmV3LWlzaCBBUEnigJlzIGZvciBEZXZlbG9wZXIgSW5z');
```

You see, the problem is that only ASCII characters are allowed in emails, so if you have non-English/Latin text you need to base64 encode it so that you can [send it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#108669).

```
function mail_utf8($to, $from_user, $from_email, $subject = '(No subject)', $message = '')
{ 
    $from_user = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($from_user)."?=";
    $subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";

    $headers = "From: $from_user <$from_email>\r\n". 
               "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
               "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

    return mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
}
```

Comment: Uhh, crap, `base64_decode` doesn't work on it's own. I think I have to trim the `=?utf-8` things first. I'm not sure exactly what I'm trying to remove, and what to keep though. Considering it spans two lines o_O Your example prints `14 New-ish API’s for Developer Ins`

Comment: This worked `mb_decode_mimeheader('=?utf-8?B?MTQgTmV3LWlzaCBBUEnigJlzIGZvciBEZXZlbG9wZXIgSW5z?=
 =?utf-8?B?cGlyYXRpb24=?=');` Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at is a string encoded in [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

To decode this string you could [use php for example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

```
echo base64_decode('MTQgTmV3LWlzaCBBUEnigJlzIGZvciBEZXZlbG9wZXIgSW5z');
```